# XML CDATA error: The element type <X> must be terminated by the matching end-tag </X>

Tags: javascript, regex, xml, cdata

I am receiving the following data in an XML feed:

```
<imagetag><![CDATA[
http://images.dealer.com/0098/65654e9beaae8aca2eeb7778e723e733x.jpg]
]></imagetag>
```

I have two problems with it:

1. When I try to validate the XML [here](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0) I get an error: `The element type "imagetag" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</imagetag>".`
2. I can't figure out a (Javascript) regular expression to extract the url. The closest I have come is: `([\s\S]*)<imagetag><!\[CDATA\[([\s\S]*)\]\]><\/imagetag>([\s\S]*)`. This works perfectly if there is no line-break after `.jpg]`, but there is!

I guess these two issues are related but I'm not sure of the cause. Any help appreciated!

Comment: well there isn't really a regex for html/xml, because it's not a _regular language_ (not saying it's weird, I mean it isn't regular by the CS definition). Have you attempted some manual parsing (looks easy to substring!)? We need more example inputs if it's just the url

Comment: See [this](https://regex101.com/r/7uLtg5/1) and only use if the XML cannot be parsed with an XML parser.

Comment: `([\s\S]*)<imagetag><!\[CDATA\[([\s\S]*)\]\s*\]><\/imagetag>([\s\S]*)` Just using your regex, but adding a `\s*` where the regex seems to break. Try this version

Answer (score 1):

First of all, realize that you don't need CDATA to represent URLs in XML.

Secondly, the reason you receive an error using XML parsers is that your data is not XML.  Your CDATA section is malformed: The [CDATA](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) end marker, [`CDEnd`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-CDEnd), cannot have a newline within it:

```
[18]    CDSect     ::=      CDStart CData CDEnd
[19]    CDStart    ::=      '<![CDATA['
[20]    CData      ::=      (Char* - (Char* ']]>' Char*))
[21]    CDEnd      ::=      ']]>'
```

Therefore, it is entirely proper for your XML parser to issue an error.

The way forward is [not to try to parse XML via regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) (although one might apply a spot check/repair on a particular problem such as finding and fixing `]]>` with embedded whitespace).  The way forward is to fix the data.  Here is your data fixed to use CDATA properly:

```
<imagetag><![CDATA[
http://images.dealer.com/0098/65654e9beaae8aca2eeb7778e723e733x.jpg
]]></imagetag>
```

or

```
<imagetag><![CDATA[http://images.dealer.com/0098/65654e9beaae8aca2eeb7778e723e733x.jpg]]></imagetag>
```

**Important:** `CDStart` must be `<![CDATA[` and `CDEnd` must be `]]>`, ***exactly with no line breaks***.  Note also that `]]>` cannot appear within the CDATA section; CDATA sections cannot nest.

If you cannot fix the data, reject the data.  It isn't proper to process textual data that is not well formed as if it were XML; it only perpetuates problems.